# open last active form C#

Tags: c#, forms, hide, switching

Hi i am relatively new to C# and am creating a troubleshooting training guide for new starters so will be creating many forms. i am currently using a simple open new form and hide current code which is working well until now. on each form i have a next and previous link label. the problem i have run into now is that i have two forms that lead to the same form and the code i am using will only go to one.

this is what i am using:

```
private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
  Home myNewForm = new Home();
  myNewForm.Visible = true;

  this.Hide();
}
```

so my question is how can i switch from the current form back to the last active form rather then a set form as in the code above?

Comment: check my answer tried to make it simple for You :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOTE

This code wasn't tested - may contain some typos

I would create an interface for it but to make it simplier - create a class which can extend the form with additional DateTime property(it could also be some kind of boolean). Like below:

```
public class FormExtended{
    public Form _form{get;set;}
    public DateTime lastActive {get;set;}
    ...
}
```

Later on for each form create an instance of this class. For example:

```
public FormExtended CreateNewForm()
{
    var extension = new FormExtended();
    extension._form = new YourForm();
    extension.lastActive = DateTime.Now;
    listOfForms.Add(extension); //listOfForms - some kind of global list to hold all instances
    return extension;

    //if you want to You can make it void and just show the form without return
    //extension._form.Show();

}
```

Now in calling method you can find latest active with linq and showit:

```
public void showLastActiveForm()
{
    var latestForm = listOfForms.OrderByDescending(x => x.lastActive).Take(1);
    latestForm._form.Show();
}
```

Comment: hi thanks for the post this has helped. had to make a few changes when adding a form cache and an additional line of code for the last section. thanks again.

Comment: It was a proof of concept. Glad it helped. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The Form which you want to open

```
 public partial class Form3 : Form
{
    public Form FormName { get; set; }
    public Form3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public Form3(Form fromName)
    {
        FormName = fromName;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void BackToFrom(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FormName.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
}
```

This is how you can go from Form2 and Form1 to Form3 and back to first place
in Form1 write this method

```
  private void ShowForm3(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new Form3(new Form1()).Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
```

In Form2 write it again but change the parameter

```
  private void ShowForm3(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new Form3(new Form2()).Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the posts but it is still just opening one and closing the previous. so say i have 3 forms. form1, form2 and form3. form1 and 2 both go to form 3 what i am wanting to do is to have the previous button on form3 choose which form to return to. so if i went from form1 - form3 it would return to form1 and if i went from form2 -form3 it would return to form2.